# Why does Galaxy Nexus i9250 official car charger have 700mA instead of 1000mA?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, charging

I discovered that the [official Samsung car charger](http://www.ebay.it/itm/Caricabatteria-da-Auto-Originale-ACADU10CBE-Per-Samsung-Galaxy-S4-Mini-i9195-/360772366111?pt=IT_Accessori_Cellulari_Caricabatterie_Dock&hash=item53ffb56f1f&_uhb=1) is rated for 700mA, but my stock wall charger has 1000mA. Is that normal? If I buy the 700mA charger, there's the risk that with the navigator on, the battery will not charge?

Instead if I buy [this that has 1000mA](http://www.amazon.it/Samsung-ECA-U16CBEG-Charger-Galaxy-N7000/dp/B005ZHD6E0/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1401818187&sr=8-2&keywords=SAMSUNG%20ECA-U16), will work with my Nexus? Written on it is "for Galaxy Note", but seems OK. Or will I have problems?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter which one you get, because the internal charging chip "should" control the maximum charging current. So unless you're planning to use your charger with another device that *can* charge at a higher current, you're wasting your money (unless they cost the same.) If for some reason, like custom ROM or poor firmware, the charging chip is not operating right, you risk burning the vias on the PCB.

Comment: Why should it not matter which one I get if my wall charger current has 1000mA? So its maximum charging current should be 1000mA, so why is the official CAR charger at 700mA? Should it be (at 1000mA) like wall charger or not?

Comment: That's the maximum current the charger can support. The current that is used by actually charging the phone is determined completely by firmware. The rest is marketing.

Comment: So a car charger of 1000mA, can be the same of one of 700mA and re-charge at the same speed. It something that I can't know without trying it, right?
But at least a car charger of 1000mA can't burn anything if I use the stock ROM and firmware, right?
However do you suggest to buy the cheapest between the two samsung charger that I linked?

Comment: The amperage marked on the charger is only the *maximum* capability of the charger, it supplies only as much amps as the phone asks for. I'd pay more attention to the quality of the charger, there's a review [here](http://www.righto.com/2012/10/a-dozen-usb-chargers-in-lab-apple-is.html).

Comment: So the question is another maybe, how much amperage does my mobile need? Maybe 1000mA because the wall charger have it? 
I read the review, but there's no way buying a car-charger from ebay/amazon to understand if it's counterfeit or not. I suppose that the only thing that I can do is to buy a car-charger with wrote "samsung" on it and hope... :D